# d3 Best practices to visualize data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, data-visualization

I am working on a project where data points are visualized in the scatterplot using d3. Since it is a web application, the region is limited and a lot of points overlap. In total there are 20k points and I allow users zooming in with a brush (and its extent) on regions, but even when zoomed in there is still a huge overlap of points. An example of such a situation:

[image]

What are good approaches to still visualize underlying points, to enhance the view or perception of the points? I was thinking about maybe using transparency, but I do not know if that would do it.

It might be worthy to note that all points represent genes, so clustering them may not be very logical in terms of representation.

Comment: Is your input data really two dimensional, or are you projecting >2 dimensions to the 2-dimensional scatterplot?

Comment: @FaKeller It really is 2d data

Comment: Ok, I've just updated the answer below with another visualization technique. If thats not what you are looking for, please provide some more information on the *purpose* of the visualization from the **user perspective**. What information should the user be able to see? How does he analyse? What conclusion may he draw?

Comment: Every point on a scatterplot represents a gene in the human brain. In total there are close to 20k of these points in a small area. Currently when you select a region of the brain, those points get a color depending on their "contribution" to that region. So when points are on top of each other, it's hard to see the different colors. Transparency is not really suitable I think. So I would like to visualize it i.e. using a magic lens. The fisheye suggestion in the other answer sounds like an interesting approach. I think clustering points will lose information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest trying d3's [fisheye plug-in](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/fisheye). It allows you to zoom and distort the scale with the mouse letting you zoom in on areas.

You can see an example of it used with a scatter/bubble chart lower on the page here: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/fisheye/

[image]

In addition, if you have overlap I would increase opacity, so you can see which points have lots of overlap vs. points that don't.

Here's an example graph with very clustered points that I created using both fisheye and opacity: http://crclayton.com/projects/fisheye/

It also allows you to hover over individual points to see a tooltip containing more details about them.

[image]

Comment: Very interesting. I never heard of something like this. One question pops up in my head though: how well can this be combined with a brush selection as brushing requires you to move your mouse?

Comment: I would use fisheye as more of an alternative to brushes rather than something in addition to it to be honest. I think including transparency like you first said and removing the point borders would accomplish something pretty reasonable.

Comment: I was thinking of indeed switching between the two and for example as soon as someone starts dragging their mouse to brush, disable the fisheye. I will look into this today

Comment: That'd probably work. Or even a button to enable/disable different modes. Let me know if you come up with something good!

Answer (score 4):

If the number of data points is of interest, then you could **cluster** the points (either on client/server side). You typically see this pattern if maps have too many markers ([example cluster map](https://researchclusters.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/clustering_example.jpg)).

---

**Edit**:

I am still not quite sure if I'm heading in the right direction. To visualize the quantity of points you could use a 3D visualization. Here is an idea taken from the [Software Cities](http://software-cities.org/jmonkeyengine/) project:

[image]

You could basically render the position of the points on the plane and create vertical cylinders - the more points on the same spot, the higher the cylinder.

Comment: I am not sure clustering would make sense in my case. Forgot to mention that, updated my post.

Comment: @Gooey A binned scatter is still a reasonable option, as in [this example](http://www.gibmetportal.gi/images/example_scatter_plot.jpg), which uses hexagonal bins, but rectangles are also an option of course. Unlike the example cluster map above, a binned scatter applies a uniform grid. Your idea of using transparency is to some extent equivalent to the binning option, since the transparencies will add up to form a heatmap-ish coloring. However, binning improves performance, since the browser doesn't have to render so many individual nodes.

Comment: @Gooey to address the need to make individual points (genes) accessible, you can implement zooming, and once the zoom level is high enough, swap the bins with the actual points.